# Can I add a hostname to my website for a domain that I do not own?

Tags: azure, web, dns

My company has a web app as an App Service in Azure. Let's say it is at "app.scottpantall.com". Our client wants their users to use our web app, but they want their customers to go to "app.company.com" to get to our web app.

My company owns our domain and our client owns their domain.

If they were to create a CNAME record that pointed their domain to my domain, would Azure allow me to add their domain as a Hostname for my web app?

They have not done so yet and I get an alert about domain ownership when I try to add their domain as a hostname.

Thanks!
-Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add any domain you want. The domain owner will need to add the CNAME record pointing to your .azurewebsites.net domain, and you will need to configure your App Service app to use that domain.

The steps needed to configure a custom domain in your DNS service and web app are at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

Comment: So My client's CNAME record **must** to point to my .azurewebsites.net domain and not my "app.scottpantall.com" domain, correct?

Comment: Pointing it to your domain may work, but I'm not 100% sure. Pointing to the .azurewebsites.net domain will work for sure.

Comment: Pointing to our domains worked. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

never worked with Azure but this might help you with adding a custom domain to your app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-custom-domain-name-portal